# What I need set to android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData observe method?

Tags: android, android-livedata

I have Fragment:

```
public class BasketFragment extends Fragment {
    ....
           public View onCreateView
             ...
```

And Room dao method return `LiveData` in `onCreateView`:

```
LiveData<List<BasketItem>> listLiveData = MyApplication.me().getDatabase().basketDao().getAll();
        listLiveData.observe(this, basketItems -> {
            BasketAdapter basketAdapter = new BasketAdapter(basketItems);
            basketAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ClickHandler());
            recyclerView.setAdapter(basketAdapter);
        });
```

I can set to `observe` method: this, getActivity() but I not understan what I need. Because observ set first parameter:

```
@NonNull LifecycleOwner owner
```

and if I set this(BasketFragment) or getActivity() - its not `LifecycleOwner`

what do you need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your activity needs to inherit from `FragmentActivity` (which would include inheriting from `AppCompatActivity`), or your fragment needs to inherit from the backport of `Fragment` (`android.support.v4.app.Fragment`).

Comment: I have import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; Can I set `this` and do nothing else?

Comment: @ip696: It is not possible to "set" `this` in Java, at least in terms of how I would use the verb "set". If you want `BasketFragment` to be the `LifecycleObserver`, the recommended approach is to have `BasketFragment` extend `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. That, in turn, will require your activity that hosts `BasketFragment` to inherit from `FragmentActivity` (directly or indirectly).

Comment: ok. I faund `public class Fragment implements ComponentCallbacks, OnCreateContextMenuListener, LifecycleOwner`. I did not correctly use the word 'set' (English is not my native language). I meant I just specify the first parameter `observe(this, ...` and I do not need to override and write logic in methods onStart, onStopp, onDestroy?

Comment: @ip696: You do not need anything for `LiveData` in those methods. You might need code there for other work to be done by `BasketFragment`.